# freeing memory in a simple avaudioengine program?

Tags: objective-c, memory-management, avfoundation, playback, avaudioengine

I'm wondering how to free memory in this simple program that plays a file through a buffer and then stops it.

```
-(void)setupAudioOne  
{  
NSError *error;  
BOOL success = NO;  

_player = [[AVAudioPlayerNode alloc] init];  

NSURL *hiphopOneURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Hip Hop 1" ofType:@"caf"]];  
AVAudioFile *hiphopOneFile = [[AVAudioFile alloc] initForReading:hiphopOneURL error:&error];  
_playerLoopBuffer = [[AVAudioPCMBuffer alloc] initWithPCMFormat:[hiphopOneFile processingFormat] frameCapacity:(AVAudioFrameCount)[hiphopOneFile length]];  
success = [hiphopOneFile readIntoBuffer:_playerLoopBuffer error:&error];  

_engine = [[AVAudioEngine alloc] init];  
[_engine attachNode:_player];  

AVAudioMixerNode *mainMixer = [_engine mainMixerNode];  

AVAudioFormat *stereoFormat = [[AVAudioFormat alloc] initStandardFormatWithSampleRate:44100 channels:2];  

[_engine connect:_player to:mainMixer fromBus:0 toBus:0 format:stereoFormat];  

[self startEngine];  
}
```

Above is the general setup of the engine and the player node.
Then we implement the player with a play button:

```
- (IBAction)play:(id)sender {  
if (!self.playerIsPlaying)  
{  
    [self setupAudioOne];  
    [_player scheduleBuffer:_playerLoopBuffer atTime:nil options:AVAudioPlayerNodeBufferLoops completionHandler:nil];  
    [_player play];  
}  
}
```

And finally we stop the player with a stop button:

```
- (IBAction)stopHipHopOne:(id)sender {  

if (self.playerIsPlaying) {  
    [_player stop];  
}
```

playerIsPlaying is just a simple BOOL that determines if the _player is playing.

So basically my question is, when you hit the stop button as this program is written now, no memory will be freed.
Surely there is a simple line of code that I can add to the stop button that frees up the memory the engine and player is using?

Any thoughts?

Comment: Is your app using ARC?

Comment: Yes it's using ARC.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, there is. After stopping the player node, you can call:

```
[_engine disconnectNodeInput:_player];
[_engine detachNode:_player];
```

I saw you're also keeping a reference to the audio buffer, so you might want to `nil` that one as well. Let me know if that doesn't work for you. Something else could be leaking.